# findNavController using context

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to use findNavController in my BindingAdapter using a View context.

Do you think it's possible ?

This is my code :

```
    @BindingAdapter("onClickForDetails", "fragment")
fun setOnClickListenerForDetails(
    view: View,
    digitalService: DigitalService,
) {
    view.setOnClickListener {
        val navDirections =
            BottomNavGraphDirections.actionFragmentToServiceDetailsFragment(
                packageName = digitalService.packageName,
                categoryId = digitalService.category
            )
        ???.findNavController().navigate(navDirections)
    }

    view.setOnLongClickListener {
        showServicesDetailsDialog(view.context, digitalService)
        return@setOnLongClickListener true
    }
}
```

Comment: [`Navigation.findNavController(view);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/Navigation#findNavController(android.view.View))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work, if your view is a view in a NavHost. This is how the extension for a View is done:

```kotlin
/**
 * Find a [NavController] associated with a [View].
 *
 * Calling this on a View not within a [NavHost] will result in an
 * [IllegalStateException]
 */
fun View.findNavController(): NavController =
        Navigation.findNavController(this)
```

Now I wouldn't recommend that, you are passing the view only for that. I would recommend to create an Interface for the onClick event and handle the navigation in the activity.